# is Object.ray_cast is not working in blender 2.8.1?

Tags: python, scripting

Using object.ray_cast I get

RuntimeError: Error: Object 'Cube' has no evaluated mesh data.

What's wrong with code?

```
        mesh = context.active_object.data
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        depsgraph  = bpy.context.evaluated_depsgraph_get()
        obj_eval = obj.evaluated_get(depsgraph)
        for vert in mesh.vertices:
            obj_eval.ray_cast(vert.co, (0.0, 0.0, 1.0))
```

Comment: Run it in object mode

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea you have to do that